# Unable to create SSL for Ubuntu VPS NextJS application

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ssl-certificate, node.js, certbot

I am trying to get an SSL for my websites hosted on Ubuntu VPS. I am receiving the following error upon running sudo certbot --nginx -v

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
Domain: webclass.in
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: 2a02:4780:11:1217:0:174f:b4a5:2: Invalid response from http://webclass.in/.well-known/acme-challenge/X2BsixJL7WqFEljetL-KJc7YMhTvqbaaWNDFl2R3ZlQ: 404

Domain: [www.webclass.in](http://www.webclass.in)
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: 2a02:4780:11:1217:0:174f:b4a5:2: Invalid response from http://www.webclass.in/.well-known/acme-challenge/HZmf5wd8t5F0zPN9-Xri3cdBpt2VkRMqydQuSbMB_Aw: 404

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary nginx configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure the listed domains point to this nginx server and that it is accessible from the internet. Kind fellows, please help, I have been struggling with this for over 8 hours now with no idea what to do. I am running a NextJS app on the frontend

This is my Nginx Configuration  -

user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# Other event-related configurations can be added here if needed
}

http {
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name webclass.in www.webclass.in;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  # for letsencrypt
   location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
     allow all;
   }


    # Additional configuration can be added here if needed

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;  # Adjust the log path as needed
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;    # Adjust the log path as needed
}

# Additional server blocks or configurations can be added here for other domains or applications

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

}